# Crop intent issue with Android M

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-crop

This is my existing code for the crop intent. This works fine on all devices

```
   private void choosePhotoFromCamera() {
System.out.println("choosePhotoFromCamera");
    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (getExternalFilesDir(null) == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "No SDcard");
        Log.e(TAG,
                "Maybe this will work : "
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        Toast.makeText(ChooseFromCamera.this, "The app needs SDcard inserted",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    File imagFile = null;
    try {
        imagFile = File.createTempFile("" + System.currentTimeMillis(),
                ".jpg", getExternalFilesDir(null));
         c= imagFile.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    uriForTempCapturePhoto = Uri.fromFile(imagFile);
    String uristring=   getPath(this, uriForTempCapturePhoto);
    uriForTempCapturePhoto= Uri.parse(uristring);*/
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriForTempCapturePhoto);
    startActivityForResult(i, TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("onActivityResult3333333333333333333333");
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE
            || requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = null;
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE) {
                uri = intent.getData();
            } else if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE) {
                uri = uriForTempCapturePhoto;
            }
            if (uri != null) {
                    try {
                    u = Uri.parse(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), c, null, null));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                }
                final Intent intent1 = new Intent(
                        "com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                    System.out.println(" uri of the image "+uriForTempCapturePhoto);

                intent1.setDataAndType(u, "image/*");
                intent1.putExtra("" +"", "true");
                intent1.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                intent1.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                intent1.putExtra("outputX", 100);
                intent1.putExtra("outputY", 100);
                intent1.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(intent1, CUT_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);

            }
        }else{
            this.finish();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == CUT_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE
            || requestCode == TAKE_GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && intent != null) {
            System.out.println("4444444444444444444444444444444");
            Bitmap bm = intent.getParcelableExtra("data");
            if(bm != null){
                System.out.println("Test : " + bm.toString());
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Null Value");
            Bitmap bmpCircular = createCircularBitmap(bm);
            System.out.println("bmpCircular1111111111111111111"+bmpCircular);
            /*if (bmpCircular == null) {
                return;
            }
            String name = null;
            String path = Utils.saveBitmap(
                    ChooseFromCamera.this.getApplicationContext(), name,
                    bmpCircular);
            if (ChooseFromCamera.this == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "called this at wrong time.");
                return;
            }
            if (path != null) {
                // sucessfully
                System.out.println("choosePhotoFromGallery1111111111111111111"+path);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                ivCamera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_camera);
                ivAccount = (RoundCornerImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_account_indicator);
                ivAccount.setImageBitmap(bmpCircular);
                ivCamera.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }*/

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            bmpCircular.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
            String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
            //String encoded = "abcdef"; 
            System.out.println("encoded value"+encoded);

            ChooseCamera.callKonyFunction(encoded);
            this.finish();
        }else{
            this.finish();
        }

    } 
}
```

Now when I test it in android M, I am getting the following exception.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: mediaStoreUri must be a MediaStore
>   Uri

To fix this issue insert image with mediastore and try to use the uri as below but this code also fails only in android M. Please help to fix.

```
if (uri != null) {
    try {
        u = Uri.parse(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), c, null, null));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{}

intent1.setDataAndType(u, "image/*");
```

Now i get only issue with Android M devices . The crop intent returns null in this case

Comment: Have you requested the permissions at runtime to access storage? http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: This may related to your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166216/android-image-crop-uri-exception